# I get a error "{ Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted." when I try send a mail with the module nodemailer from Node JS

Tags: node.js, email, authentication, smtp

I am new in Node js and I try send a message like example to other e-mail and when I run the file in the terminal from linux I get this error:

```js
root@me:/home/memee/Desktop/test/NodeJS/mail# nano example.js
root@me:/home/memee/Desktop/test/NodeJS/mail# node example.js
{ Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 77-v6sm41437784pga.40 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/memee/Desktop/test/NodeJS/mail/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/home/memee/Desktop/test/NodeJS/mail/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1335:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/home/memee/Desktop/test/NodeJS/mail/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:366:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/memee/Desktop/test/NodeJS/mail/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:762:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/memee/Desktop/test/NodeJS/mail/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/home/memee/Desktop/test/NodeJS/mail/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:510:47)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 77-v6sm41437784pga.40 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

I understand that my error is the login but my password and email is correct.

My code :

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'example@gmail.com',
    pass: 'here I put my password'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'from@gmail.com',
  to: 'to@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

my version of node and npm :

```html
root@me:~# node --version
v8.11.3
root@me:~# npm --v
6.1.0
root@me:~#
```

I used this tutorial :[tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your email and password are not matching, look at the error message: `response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.`.

see this part of your code:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'example@gmail.com', // here use your real email
    pass: 'here I put my password' // put your password correctly (not in this question please)
  }
});
```

If you make a login with your user and password, you will be able to send emails.

I used the same code to send this email, but with my credentials:
[image: I used the same code to send this email]

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this recently and it was related to the [Less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) settings on the account.

Choosing "Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps" fixed it.

[image]

Comment: With the current google security, right after this fix please look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981381/6821441, since you will have to disable captcha

Answer (score 5):

Turn on Allow less secure apps at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 5):

I'd the same problem earlier but after **removing `'@gmail.com'`** from username worked fine for me.
Error `'535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted'` occurs only in following mentioned cases:

1. Wrong credentials.
2. adding `@gmail.com` in the username, avoid it!
3. two-factor authentication enabled. If yes, then disable it.
4. https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps if it is OFF, turn it ON to enable lesssecureapps.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and worked for me:

#1 Create a google app password https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

#2 Use:

```
host: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: 587,
auth: {
  user: "Your username here e.g:abc@gmail.com",
  pass: "Your password here"
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Step1 However, you need to allow less secure apps from your google account to send emails. [Through this link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4MSdNpo50FRat2V8nQQA9RvMOiB8jAgs9R9IvyDoMwHkedoM9E33infQKi0Z2iHNcu5QUJnR_KJndCSf7fKG5TKDlSv9Q)  . Allow less secure apps From your Google Account

Read below instruction [Enable imap](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=BadCredentials&visit_id=637502674581505852-3188229908&rd=2#cantsignin)

Short url for Enable IMAP in IMAP access section [GO TO URL](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop)

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: 587,
secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
type:"oauth2",
auth: {
  user: "myusernmae@gmail.com", // generated ethereal user
  pass: "Mypassword", // generated ethereal password
}});

transporter.verify(async function(error, success) {
if (error) {
  console.log(error);
} else {
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
      to: "manoj@gmail.com, baz@example.com", // list of receivers
      subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
      text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
      html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
  });
  console.log(info);
  console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
}});
```

Working Example

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution to it. Cheers!!!

- Create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport

  ```
   transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
        user: 'yourEmail', //Remove '@gmail.com' from your username.
        pass: 'yourPassword' 
     }
   });
  ```
- Turn on Allow less secure apps at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
- Allow Less secure app access : https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
- Done!!

If someone facing below issue

```
(firebase functions) Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /
```

The solution to it is :

- Delete your Cloud Functions
- Update Firebase CLI `npm install -g firebase-tools`
- Re-deploy your functions