# Nodemailer throws error Invalid login: 534-5.7.14

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I found this error while i'm trying to send an email from one Gmail account to another. How to solve this error ? Help me on it.

There were an error:

> Invalid login: 534-5.7.14
>    Please
>   log in via 534-5.7.14 your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 
>   Learn more at 534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754
>   a90-v6sm7292588pfg.106 - gsmtp

I have already try **Allow less secure apps to be ON**
but still same error.
it working correctly when i run application on  local machine but this error on server machine

Please help me

Comment: Show us your code. It's most likely "Allow less secure apps" or Captcha

Answer (score 48):

You might need to allow access to your Gmail account.

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

**Edit (after your comment)**

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport

```
transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
        user: 'yourEmail', 
        pass: 'yourPassword' 
    }
});
```

your 'nodemailer.createTransport' should look something similar.

Comment: Hi @Shanil I try above but no luck  this my code `var sender = 'smtps://EMAILID%40gmail.com'   
var password = 'PASSWORD' var transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport(sender + ':' + password + '@smtp.gmail.com');`

Comment: Hi @sways it would be easier if you edit your question and post the code snippet.

Comment: I have also updated my answer. please have a look at it.

Comment: try the above code snippet  but same error  in local machine working correctly. issue on server machine

Comment: Previously also the issue was only in the server?

Comment: have you tried this also https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha  ??

Comment: I tried this solution. It works for some hours. But gmail again starts blocking mail sending requests.

Comment: @Nikhil are you trying to send a large number of emails?

Comment: @RohitParte Great :)

Comment: @shanil-arjuna nope. Just one email. I finally decided to move to Amazon SES SMTP. I verified by GMail address under SES and started sending emails through Lambda without any issues.

Comment: @Nikhil Great :)

Comment: the low security methode was temporary and i couldn't use it in production but I found an article that made it easier using OAuth 

  [here](http://blog.bessam.engineer/How-to-use-nodemailer-with-GMail-and-OAuth)

Answer (score 26):

If you use GMAIL service as a transporter,

Step-1: Log in to your gmail account.

Step-2: Enable less secure app access and/or DisplayUnlockCaptcha on your gmail account.

Step-3: Follow a 6-step guide on [Sign in with App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Step-4: Replace your transporter password with the 16-character generated app password you obtain from Step-3 above.

These four easy steps solved my problem.

Comment: it worked thanks! But its not working with the normal gmail. It worked with email@website.com

Comment: This is much better way. Now i am able to use in aws lambda.

Comment: This worked for Firebase Cloud functions, thank you!

Comment: This worked for me as well.  No matter what I tired prior, google did not like my password while running my app on my live host.  My local host was perfectly fine.  Not until I followed this process, its now working in both my local and live environments.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, this occurs only because of two major issues

1. I yet to enable the less secure option in google account under security
2. You should allow the google account to be accessed by the third party application. See https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: For me the second one was the deal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got  the same issue as this works fine using postman client on local environment.

But giving the error or aws-linux vpc i configured.

**So this can be fixed as:**

```
let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 587,
ignoreTLS: false,
secure: false,
auth: {
    user: "your mail",
    pass: 'your password'
}
});
module.exports = transporter;
```

Please make sure you have allow access to your account and less secure apps setting should be turned on.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to open the below link and enable to allow your google account access.

- https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

This will allow Google to complete this additional step when signing into a new device or application.

Answer (score 0):

the low security methode was temporary and i couldn't use it in production but I found an article that made it easier using OAuth to connect to GMail [here](http://www.bessamblog.tech/How-to-use-nodemailer-with-GMail-and-OAuth)
with an example code and it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

For gmail, you need to allow 2 step authorisation and then set up a 16 digit app password.  Use that password with your gmail address, - not your regular password.  Should be good to go!