# Nodemailer with Gmail account not working inside Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I am trying to send a reset-password email from a `noreply.myappname@gmail.com` email to my users using a Gmail account and `nodemailer` inside a `Cloud Function`.

I have followed this [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js) that is not working.
Here is the error i am getting :

[image]

So i have tried what is written : `Please log in via your web browser and then try again` .
I have also set the `lessSecureApp` to `ON` in my Gmail account.
I am receiving security alerts on my main Gmail account each time a Cloud Function is ran and this is still not working.

What am I doing wrong here ? (I have the exact same code as the sample, just configured the `functions.config().gmailEmail` and `functions.config().gmailPassword` with the ones of my account).

How to not have security alerts and how to make it work without the need of logging in a browser (even if it doesn't work either) which would be weird for a production app ?

Comment: From an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/39) in the same repository, it seems like you also need to enable `DisplayUnlockCaptcha` in your Gmail account in addition to enabling `lessSecureApp`. You can also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980436/) for additional things to try. Another behavior you might be seeing is that it works for some time and then fails, which is caused by Gmail’s sending [quota](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/quickstarts/email-users#functions-code).

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! It helps indeed as i know i can't use this API to send emails anyway because of the quota :)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you could try activating `DisableUnlockCaptcha` in your G-mail account to continue in this path, but you would run into the G-mail email send [quota](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839#zippy=%2Cyou-have-reached-a-limit-for-sending-mail) mentioned in the repository [readme](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/quickstarts/email-users#functions-code). Just leaving this answer in case other users have doubts or have run into their quota limit and see an error. Since the repository recommends using a third party email provider such as SendGrid, [this guide](https://fireship.io/lessons/sendgrid-transactional-email-guide/) for sending email from Firebase functions with SendGrid could be useful.